# Информация о сообществе вк

Tags: android, java, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Нужно получить информацию о сообществе вк через VKApi в Java.
Делаю так:

```
VKRequest request = VKApi.groups().getById(VKParameters.from(VKApiConst.FIELDS, "21398398", "members_count"));
```

но выдаёт ошибку №100 "VKError (API errorVKError (code: 100;; One of the parameters specified was missind or invalid: groups_ids is undefined)). Может, я не так написал id группы?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решение:

```
VKRequest request = VKApi.groups().getById(VKParameters.from(VKApiConst.GROUP_ID,  "21398398", VKApiConst.FIELDS, "members_count"));
```